# Sending email in emacs w/ request package and mailgun

Tags: email, emacs, http-post, elisp, mailgun

I am trying to write an elisp function to send email using a mailgun account.

Here is what I have tried:

```
(require 'request) 
(defun send-mail (api-key from-url to-name to-address subject message)       
  "Sends an email using Mailgun account"                                     
  (request                                                                   
   (concat "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/" from-url "/messages")               
   :type "POST"                                                              
   :data '(("from" . (concat "Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@" from-url ">"))   
           ("to" . (concat to-name " <" to-address ">"))                     
           ("subject" . subject)                                             
           ("text" . message))                                               
   :headers '(("api" . api-key))                                             
   :parser 'json-read                                                        
   :success (function*                                                       
             (lambda (&key data &allow-other-keys)                           
               (message "I sent: %S" (assoc-default 'form data))))))
```

I am getting the error "Wrong type argument: integerp, concat" from the "from" section in :data. Not sure what I am doing wrong, or if this is even the correct approach to be taking.

Comment: Is the `from-url` a **string** or are you trying to pass it as an **integer** -- e.g., **55** -- without quotation marks?  Is there a reason you are not using the built-in email elisp libraries, or one of the popular third-party elisp libraries?  You can, of course, reinvent the wheel -- but why?

Comment: From-url is a string. This is an easier option than setting up my own SMTP server to send the emails, and the request library seems to be relatively standard? Unless there is another I should be using

Comment: Try setting up a simple message with something like:  `(message "What is the value of from-url? %s |  Is it a string? %s | or, Is it an integer? %s" from-url (stringp from-url) (integerp from-url))` and place it just after the doc-string in your `send-mail` function and see what it returns.  `concat` only works with strings and it looks like your question states the error comes from `concat`.  If not already done, also enable full error message reporting with `(setq debug-on-error t)`

Comment: See this related thread where the answer discusses how to evaluate components of a list, and explains the difference between a single quote versus a back-quote and a comma preceding items within the list that need to be evaluated:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/17155/2287  See also the comments underneath the answer for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

In this section:

```
   :data '(("from" . (concat "Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@" from-url ">"))   
           ("to" . (concat to-name " <" to-address ">"))                     
           ("subject" . subject)                                             
           ("text" . message))
```

you are quoting the entire list literally with a single quote (`'`), but you actually want the `concat` function calls to be evaluated before that.

You can use a backquote instead, and put a comma before the parts that should be evaluated:

```
   :data `(("from" . ,(concat "Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@" from-url ">"))   
           ("to" . ,(concat to-name " <" to-address ">"))                     
           ("subject" . subject)                                             
           ("text" . message))
```

[The question lawlist linked to in the comments](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17155/simple-request-el-usage) explains this in more detail.